# Is it possible to use multiple instances of the Visual Studio 11 simulator for debugging multiplayer metro apps?

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-debugging, multiplayer

I know the solution for doing this for windows phone apps. But it seems to me, that this must be accomplished some other way. I would be pleased, if anybody got any insight here..

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  You could conceivably use a hyper-v solution and have multiple OS's running out on your machine, the connect to them using the remote debugging tools?